# How should be defined the seasons of a year as an input variable for ANN in matlab

Tags: input, neural-network

I wanted to define the season of a year(4 seasons) as one of the inputs variables for neural network in matlab .Can I just use numbers from 1 to 4 ?Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a categorical variable, it's better to use 1-hot coding:

```
0001: summer
0010: fall
0100: winter
1000: spring
```

So, your season input will become 4 binary inputs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer means that for all of 92 days in spring I should put 0001and etc?

Comment: Exactly. But make sure they are 4 different binary inputs, not a single '0001' input value.

Comment: So can I use binary inputs and integer inputs at the same time as inputs of ANN in Matlab?

Comment: They're binary in the sense that the only possible values are 0 or 1, but you'll use integers anyway, not true or false. Depending on your activation function, even -1 or 1 may be better. Test and see what gives you best test results.

Comment: Test results you mean test performance or validation performance?sorry for asking this question

Comment: If you're using a validation set, then it is the validation performance.

Comment: So sorry for asking lots of questions but I could not find exact answer when I googled them.I have  divided my data to 3 subsets train,validation,test .The best network is the one which has lower validation performance or test performance or just performance?Thanks in advance for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally there are 2 ways to do this: use one input for each category and scale the integer values, e.g. (0,...,4) for season to continuous values in the range of other input variables. However, this approach would assume that you have some hierarchy in the categories, let's say Spring is 'better' or 'higher' than Summer. Since this is not the case, you would need to create one input node for each possible realization of a category, i.e. 4 input variables for the season where all are set to '0' except the category that is active, which is set to '1'. I would not advice to encode the integer categorical variables into binary values, and thus reduce the number of required input nodes. You would end up with a correlation bias among categories that have the value set to '1' at the same time, e.g. for (hot, mild, cold) = ([0,1], [1,0], [1,1]), the encoding for 'hot' would mean an artificial similarity to 'cold' and 'mild', since they share the same bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answeer